# Windows Subsystem Linux (WSL) don't catch ctrl+backspace with power shell

Tags: powershell, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I use Windows Subsystem Linux (WSL) under Windows 10 via power shell.

It don't catch ctrl+backspace? (it just backspace) while powershell correctly catch it if I use some other commands, not in linux.

Comment: Use any terminal emulator in Windows, for example, cmder, conemu, wsltty etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Linux you must type Alt+Backspace to achieve the same effect that Ctrl+Backspace in Windows terminals.

Comment: Is that documented anywhere ?

Comment: Well, I haven't found any official documentation, but this answer talks about the relationship between bash and emacs. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/307732/147871